# Google Maps won't center

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, centering

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and have implemented Google Maps in a modal, which dynamically shows the position of a producer. Everything works fine, except for the fact that the marker won't center. Instead it's always located in the upper-left corner (seen only if scrolled).

I have tried many things here but can't get it to work. Can someone please help me out here?

**html:**

```
  <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3 id="myModalLabel">Test</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="modal-left" class="modal-body left">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body right">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row span12">
  <div id="allProducers"></div>
</div>
```

**relevant css:**

```
#map {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**js:**

```
function largeMap(latitude, longitude){
    var Latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    var Options = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: Latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var Map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), Options);

    var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: Latlng,
        map:Map,
        title:"The Map"
    });

    Marker.setMap(Map);
}

$('.modal-btn').click(function(){

    var producerId = $(this).attr('id');

    GetProducer(producerId, function(data) {
        var titel = data.name;

        $('#myModalLabel').html(titel);

        $('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
          google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
          map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(data.longitude, data.latitude));
        })
    });
});
```

*Note: I would love to create a jsFiddle, but because I'm using a modal (included in Twitter Bootstrap), which probably is a part of the problem that won't work.*

Comment: If you break on `map.setCenter(...` does `data...` contain the correct values?

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Yes, data.latitude and data.longitude contains of the correct values inside of "$('#myModal').on('shown'...". However, if console.log (data.latitude, or actually whatever) after "map.setCenter..." nothing is shown. It's like the script stops running on that line. Strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you need access to the `Map` object (and highly recommend just reusing your `LatLng` object), you could do it like this:

```
var Map; 
var Markerlatlng

function largeMap(latitude, longitude){
  Markerlatlng= new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

  var Options = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: Markerlatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  Map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), Options);

  var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: Markerlatlng,
    map:Map,
    title:"The Map"
  });

  Marker.setMap(Map);
}



$('.modal-btn').click(function(){

  var producerId = $(this).attr('id');

  GetProducer(producerId, function(data) {
    var titel = data.name;

    $('#myModalLabel').html(titel);

    $('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
      google.maps.event.trigger(Map, 'resize');
      Map.setCenter(Markerlatlng);
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! However, you should remove "var" from the second "var Markerlatlng", otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mixed the cases:

```
 var Map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), Options);
```

and

```
 map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(data.longitude, data.latitude));
```

Try this instead

```
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), Options);
```

Aren't there any issues in your firebug/chrome console?

Comment: You're right about the issues, totally missed that in Chrome console. "Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'setCenter'", which of course refers to "map". What can I do instead?